# How do two isomorphic objects relate the same way to other objects.

Tags: category-theory

I read the following statement in "Category Theory for Computing Science" by Barr and Wells

"From a categorist's point of view there is no reason to distinguish between two isomorphic objects in a category, sinc the interesting fact about a mathematical object is the way it relates to other mathematical objects and **two isomorphic objects relate to other objects in the same way**."

Does this mean that if A is isomorphic to B and if there is an arrow f between A and C then there should be an arrow f between B and C?

Comment: That is certainly one consequence.

Comment: can you prove that if A is isomorphic to B and if there is an arrow f between A and C then there should be an arrow f between B and C? I am not sure if that is possible since arrows are partly characterised by their source and target, right?

Comment: arrow $f:A\rightarrow C$ corresponds with arrow $f\circ i:B\rightarrow C$ where $i:B\rightarrow A$ is an isomorphism. And arrow $g:B\rightarrow C$ corresponds with arrow $g\circ i^{-1}:A\rightarrow C$

Comment: Not sure i see what you are trying to do there @drhab . What do you mean by correspond with.

Comment: My former comment answers your question (if $A$ and $B$ are iso and there is an arrow $f:A\rightarrow C$, then is there an arrow $B\rightarrow C$?) with "yes". This arrow is not $f$ itself, though. Were you wondering about that? The map $f\mapsto f\circ i$ is a bijection and finds its inverse in the map $g\mapsto g\circ i^{-1}$.

Comment: if A is isomorphic to B and if there is an arrow f between A and C then there should be an arrow f between B and C? Isn't that true regardless of the fact that A is isomorphic to B, in case there is an arrow from B to A (the arrow doesnt have to be isomorphic to A->B). So yeah, I am still trying to understand what "two isomorphic objects relate to other objects in the same way." means

Comment: Ah, i guess perhaps what the text means is that if two objects A and B are isomorphic, then every object A is related to (by an outwards or inwards arrow), B is related to as well by an outwards or inwards arrow as well. Thanks @drnab

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are not isomorphic then it can happen that the homset between $B$ and $C$ is empty and the homset between $A$ and $C$ is not. $A$ and $B$ isomorphic is a sufficient (not necessary) condition to avoid that.

Comment: Right. Thanks @drnab!